# Convert duplicated values to non-duplicated by appending a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database is case-insensitive, but imported data are coming from external case-sensitive system. Unique index consists of 3 columns, but due to case-sensitivity issue, all 3 columns are no longer unique.

Example:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 | abc  |
|    1 |    2 | aBc  |
|    1 |    2 | ABC  |
|    1 |    3 | abc  |
|    2 |    4 | abc  |
+------+------+------+
```

I would expect to append a number only to values in Col3 causing index based on all 3 column duplicated. This does not matter what number will be appended to a particular "abc" version. Expected result:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 | abc1 |
|    1 |    2 | aBc2 |
|    1 |    2 | ABC3 |
|    1 |    3 | abc  |
|    2 |    4 | abc  |
+------+------+------+
```

Both solutions can be accepted: updating the source table or "on-the-fly" select.

I am using SQL Server 2017 locally and Azure SQL on production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`.  The following assumes a case-insensitive collation (the default)

```
select t.col1, t.col2,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by col1, col2, col3) = 1
             then col1
             else col3 + convert(varchar(255), row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1) )
        end) as new_col3
from t;
```

You can easily turn this into an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when count(*) over (partition by col1, col2, col3) = 1
                   then col1
                   else col3 + convert(varchar(255), row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1) )
              end) as new_col3
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set col3 = new_col3
    where new_col3 <> col3;
```

You can easily add a case-insensitive collation using `COLLATE`, if it is not the default.